# Can't mount NTFS partitions, and don't have Windows installed to fix them

Tags: permissions, mount, windows, ntfs, disk

I've just installed 16.04. Ubuntu. I installed it on old C:/ partition (250GB SSD disk, all place for Linux, ext4) so I don't have dual-boot and I am not able to boot Windows because it doesn't exist on any of my disks. I also have two HDD disks (750GB - 2 NTFS partition 250 and 500, 250 GB - one NTFS partition). My problem is that I can't mount these disks with write and read permission.

Later I couldn't mount the disks at all due to an error about hibernated Windows (which I don't have). I used the program Disk (preinstalled) and added 'ro' to the mount options. It helped with mounting the disk, but I can't write or edit anything. Can you help?

Comment: Windows fast start up sets hibernation on all NTFS partitions. You must have that off, or Linux NTFS driver will not mount NTFS read/write. If you do not have Windows you may be able to fix with a Windows repair disk or installer with repair console. If not using Windows do not use NTFS as you cannot run chkdsk from Linux and it will eventually need both chkdsk and defrag.

Comment: @oldfred OK but there might be other reasons for using NTFS. I agree that it's not the best option, but it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, install VirtualBox and then head over to the [official Microsoft VMs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) website. Download a VM (for instance, you might chose *IE8 on Win7*) and then unzip the file.

Then you need to:

- import the OVA file (just double click on it and VirtualBox will open a wizard)
- set up USB 2.0 in the VM properties (you will need to add the proprietary extension pack in VirtualBox)
- boot the VM
- connect the hard drive and attach it to the VM
- in the virtualized Windows environment, open the prompt as administrator
- type `chkdsk /f E:` where `E:` must be replaced with the correct drive letter
- cleanly turn off the VM
- from Ubuntu run `sudo sync`

Disconnect the drive from your computer and connect it again.

If you encounter other error related to hibernation, please check this answer:

https://askubuntu.com/a/145904/271

Comment: I don't know, it looks like it could help but know I can't run VM because system just freeze. I think I will go back to Windows :D I hope this weekend I will go back to problem...

Comment: Back to Windows? Before taking such drastic steps please try to solve the freezing. That is surely a separate issue.

Comment: I just formatted partitions to ext4. Now everything works fine in terminal, but I still get error "Partition is read-only" in gui manager (program Files). Any idea?

Comment: The idea is to follow the answer. :)